# How to define a long or a short vowel in Latin words?

Tags: pronunciation, vowel

If there appears no macron on a vowel, which is part of a monophthong, then how can I define whether it is a long vowel or a short vowel？
[image]

Comment: Using images instead of text makes it impossible to search for specific words, impossible to copy specific parts, unindexable by search engines, and totally useless for people that rely on text-to-voice translation to read the question. There is also no citation for where the image was copied from.

Answer (score 8):

No way to know. That's what the macrons are for!

For example, *alium* means "another", while *ālium* means "garlic"; *anus* means "old woman", while *ānus* means "ring"; *malum* means "bad", while *mālum* means "apple tree"; and so on. You just need to learn the long and short vowels as part of learning a word.

Comment: Learning vowel lengths correctly applies to both vocabulary and morphology. To work out the vowel lengths of a given word, one needs to check both a dictionary for the word and a grammar for the ending.

Comment: Long-o _malum_ means 'apple'; it's long-o _malus_ that means 'apple tree'.

Comment: @gaufridus long-a, rather, but the point is a good one. Also it's convenient to mention that _mālus_ (and _pirus_ and other names of trees ending in _-us_) are all feminine, unlike most other words in their declension.

Comment: @Wtrmute Well, that's a somewhat embarrassing error; thanks for pointing it out.